# How to create a calculation that prints the previous month based on the expiration date stored in a txt file

Tags: python, for-loop, split, text-files

I would like to calculate how to set the dates given in the text file to one month before as a reminder for the expiration date for their WOF.

I have the code which does the reminder BUT for the whole list and not just those who passed [P or F in the text file].

This is the code to access the text file.

```
file = input("Enter file name: ")
f = open(file)

f = open(file, "r")
for line in f:
   print(line)

f.close()
```

[This is a screenshot of the text file using the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNJru.png)

I have created array to store the expiry date. But i dont know how to split with the marks because the dates are integers and the mark is a string. This why i did the whole list and just those who passed.

```
day = []
month = []
year = []
mark = []

for line in expiry:
  fields = line.split("/")
  day.append(int(fields[0]))
  month.append(int(fields[1]))
  year.append(int(fields[2]))
  mark.append(fields[3]) <- This doesn't work
```

I have created code that decreases the month but it decreases every value not just those who passed.

```
month[:] = [x - 1 for x in month]
```

I created variables for those who expiration are on January and changed the year

```
month[3] = 12
month[14] = 12
month[15] = 12
month[18] = 12
month[30] = 12
month[32] = 12

year[3] = 2025
year[14] = 2022
year[15] = 2024
year[18] = 2020
year[30] = 2020
year[32] = 2020
```

and outputted the reminder here

```
reminder = list(zip(day, month, year))
```

[Results of the whole file reminder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLRmi.png)